# String condition to bool

Tags: flutter, dart, dynamic, backend, dynamic-programming

I am busy trying to create an if statement on the front end from the back end string value

[image]

The image above is from the back end and I replaced the **$blody1$** with

[image]

so in the end it will be something like this **[Guest].length > 1**

Is there a way to convert it to a true or false, if not any pointers to help. I wanted to move the logic to the back end but belive I will have the same issue there aswell.

Side note the end  result should be like {"color" : "blue"} OR {"color" : "orange"}

MY CODE

```
const start = "\$";
const end = "\$";

final startIndex = str.indexOf(start);
final endIndex = str.indexOf(end, startIndex + start.length);

String tValue =
    str.substring(startIndex + start.length, endIndex);
String tcondition = str.substring(endIndex + 1);
print(getValue(tValue).toString() + tcondition);
```

Thank you

Comment: There is no way to evaluate an arbitrary string as code.  That's both impractical and would be an arbitrary code execution exploit waiting to happen.  At best you can build a `Map<String, dynamic>` to map the string `"Guest"` to the object referenced by the `Guest` variable, and then use that when parsing the incoming string.

Comment: Understood, I Will need to investigate a bit more... Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check like below code

```
void main() {
   var data = {"body1":["Guest"]};
  
  print(data["body1"][0]=="Guest");//true
}
```

**Update**

Check the body length

```
Color color = Colors.green;
 if(data["body1"].length>1){
   // set your color
   color = Colors.red;
 }
```

Comment: It is dynamic, so sometimes it would be ["Guest", "Admin"] and so forth. The idea behinf the code is in the end it will be {"color" : "green"} or {"color" : "orange"}. With the condtion it can chnage as well. For example it may be something like userId == "27234"

Comment: You got the point, but you change for a different role can change it manually or dynamically

Comment: It will be populated dynamically

Comment: const start = "\$";
              const end = "\$";

              final startIndex = str.indexOf(start);
              final endIndex = str.indexOf(end, startIndex + start.length);

              String tValue =
                  str.substring(startIndex + start.length, endIndex);
              String tcondition = str.substring(endIndex + 1);
              print(getValue(tValue).toString() + tcondition);

Comment: The code above is what i used but saw that it wasn't working as expcted

Comment: Have updated the description with more information. Thank you

Comment: you want to change the color based on body length, if length is greater than 1 you will show blue or orange

Comment: Exactly that idea

Comment: updated my answer have a look